# AWS Lambda Layers & Lerna.js

Tags: node.js, serverless, lerna, monorepo, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to use Lerna.js to create Serverless monorepo, in bench with AWS Lambda Layers.
Technically I want to share my root node_modules between Lambdas as Layer.

But I faced with problem that my own lerna sub-packages exist in node_modules as symlink, and it's a problem.
Do you have any guide, advice, how symlink could be replaced with "real" folder in node_modules in context of lerna.js usage?

[image]

*** I've just created issue in lerna.js repo, but maybe smbd here have any suggests (https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2154).